# Shared library function does working correctly after first dlopen

Tags: c, websocket

I am creating a websocket server in C. Since taking a server down, recompiling it, and running it again is counterproductive to what a server app should do, I am looking for ways to dynamically load in my functions so that I can keep the main server app running while being able to alter / create new functions that will be used in it. I created a function that allows me to call a function by name with correct arguments like you would a normal function call, but when I go to call it the second time it does not do the same thing the second time I call it dynamically. To lay out my problem by steps, consider the following situations:

**Situation 1**

1. Start server application without calling sendMessage dynamically.
2. Connect to the websocket server via browser.
3. After successful connection send a message to the server (I use `Hello World`)
4. Server will echo the message the client sent.
5. Send the same message to the server again.
6. Server will echo message again. (this is when the server sendMessage function is not loaded dynamically
7. Repeating steps 5 and 6 will not cause the client to disconnect.

Now for the situation using a dynamic version of the servers sendMessage function to echo the client message.

**Situation 2**

1. Start server application while allowing sendMessage to be called using loadFunction.
2. Connect to the websocket server via browser.
3. After successful connection send a message to the server (again I use `Hello World`)
4. Server will echo the message the client sent like it should.
5. Send the same message to the server again.
6. This time the server does not echo the message the client sent.
7. Sending more messages after the first will eventually cause the connection to end (This is where I am having a problem

Situation 1 is when my function `sendMessage` is called normally (not through `loadFunction`) while situation 2 is where I replace `sendMessage` with my `loadFunction` call that loads the library holding `sendMessage`, assigns it to a location function variable (see code) and call the function like it would normally.

I am thinking that the problem lies with the write function in `sendMessage` when I dynamically load it. But the function works perfectly when I don't load it dynamically which is odd to me.

My question is why is why would my `sendMessage` function operate differently from when I call it normally and when I call it dynamically? Below is some code and output from both situations

**sendMessage.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "include/structs.h"
//#include "include/functions.h"

/*
 * sendMessage: this function is used then we want to send message (s)
 *              of length (len) from the server to a client (sock)
 *
 * ARGUMENTS
 * sock:    the socket where we want the message to go
 * s:       A string containing the message we want to send
 * len: the length of the string s
 */
void *sendMessage(int sock, char *s, int len) {
    int frameCount;
    uint16_t len16;
    char frame[10];
    char *reply =   malloc(sizeof(char) * (len + 8));

    frame[0] =  '\x81';

    if (len <= 125) {
        frame[1] = len;
        frameCount = 2;
    } else if (len >= 126 && len <= 65535) {
        frame[1] = 126;
        len16 = htons(len);
        memcpy(frame + 2, &len16, 2);
        frameCount = 4;
    } else {
        frame[1] = 127;
        //NOTE: HAVE NOT FULLY CONFIGURED A MESSAGE OF THIS LENGTH (TODO)
        //frame[2] = (char)( ((char)len >> 56) & (char)255 );
        //frame[3] = (char)( ((char)len >> 48) & (char)255 );
        //frame[4] = (char)( ((char)len >> 40) & (char)255 );
        //frame[5] = (char)( ((char)len >> 32) & (char)255 );
        //frame[6] = (char)( ((char)len >> 24) & (char)255 );
        frame[7] = (char)( ((char)len >> 16) & (char)255 );
        frame[8] = (char)( ((char)len >> 8) & (char)255 );
        frame[9] = (char)( ((char)len) & (char)255 );
        frameCount = 10;
    }//END IF

    memcpy(reply, frame, frameCount);
    memcpy(reply + frameCount, s, len);

    //printf("sock: %d\ts: %s\tlen: %d\n", sock, s, len);
    if (write(sock, reply, strlen(reply)) <= 0) {
        printf("\n\nWE ARE NOT WRITING!!\n\n");
    } else {
        //printf("we did write\n");
    }//END IF

    free(reply);
    reply = NULL;

    return NULL;
}//END FUNCTION
```

**loadFunction.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include "include/functions.h"

int checkForError(char *error) {
    if (error != NULL) {
        printf("ERROR: %s\n", error);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }//END IF

    return 0;
}//END IF

void * loadFunction(char *func, void ** args) {
    void *handle;
    //void * (*alterStruct)(int sock, char *action);

    int filenameLength;
    char * filename;
    //void *(*funcPtr);


    filenameLength = strlen("lib/lib") + strlen(func) + strlen(".dll");
    filename = malloc(sizeof(char) * (filenameLength + 1));
    strcpy(filename, "lib/lib");
    strcat(filename, func);
    strcat(filename, ".dll");

    handle = dlopen(filename, RTLD_LAZY);
    free(filename);
    if (!handle) {
        checkForError(dlerror());
    }//END IF

    dlerror();

    if (strncmp(func, "sendMessage", strlen(func)) == 0) {
        void * (*funcPtr)(int, char *, int);
        //*(void **) (&funcPtr) = dlsym(handle, func);
        funcPtr = (void *)dlsym(handle, func);
        checkForError(dlerror());
        (*funcPtr)((int)args[0], (char *)args[1], (int)args[2]);
        //free(*(void **)(&funcPtr));
        //*(void **) (&funcPtr) = NULL;
    }// else if (strncmp(func, "alterStruct", strlen(func)) == 0) {
        //void * (*funcPtr)(int sock, char *action);
    //} else if (strncmp(func, "execute", strlen(func)) == 0) {
        //void * (*funcPtr)(const char *command, clientStruct s, FILE **in, FILE **out, FILE **err);
    //} else {
        //void * (*funcPtr)(int sock, char *s, int len);
    //}//END IF

    dlclose(handle);
    handle = NULL;
    return NULL;


    return NULL;

}//END loadFunction
```

If you need more code to solve this problem I have it accessable on [GitHub here](https://github.com/mic1780/websockets/tree/dynamic) (the dynamic branch is where the problem can be found)

Also, I am using Cygwins' GNU gcc compiler (which I have never have a problem compiling on) to compile my application and libraries so I may not have access to certain Linux commands (for example `dlmopen`). That said, please do not say use a different compiler because I've had no other problems thus far and I do not intend on changing how I compile my code.

I did not document the command I use to compile just the libsendMessage.dll used in `loadFunction`. you can obtain it using the following

```
gcc -c -fPIC sendMessage.c
mv sendMessage.o objects/sendMessage.o
gcc -shared -o lib/libsendMessage.dll objects/sendMessage.o libfunctions.c
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out my problem and it is quite an odd one.

When i was testing the `sendMessage` function using my dynamic method i `printf` exactly what was being sent through the socket and apparently it was sending the correct message. However, it was also sending the characters from my filename variable in the `loadFunction` function which to me is strange that the memory address was accessable to `sendMessage` when it was `malloc`ed, freed and set to NULL way before the function call to the dynamic `sendMessage` was called.

**Solution**

After I opened my library with `dlopen(filename, RTLD_LAZY)` I used `memset(filename, '\0', filenameLength)` to write null characters to the memory address of filename making the string contain all null characters which when accessed as a character counts as a end of string.

I'm not sure why I am having to use memset so much in this application but i know that it has fixed string bugs for me multiple times.